# Openmp Parallel For Invalid Controlling Predicate for (i=1;i<ngl_-1;++i)

Tags: c++, openmp

Hello this is my code for a multigrid solver. I am trying to do this particular code segment to parallelize using openmp parallel for. But I get the error saying

```
 " invalid controlling predicate for (i=1;i<ngl_-1;++i)"
```

Could someone help?

```cc
void Solver::RBGS(int l_level)
{
    int x=level-l_level;
    double ngl_= lev_Vec[x]->Grid::get_ngpValue();
    double h2_= 4.0/((ngl_-1)*(ngl_-1));
    int midval = 0.5*(ngl_-1);
    ///---------------------------------- RED UPDATE -------------------------------------------------//
    int i,j;

    #pragma omp parallel default(shared)
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=1;i<ngl_-1;++i)
    {
        if(i & 1)
        {

            for(j=1;j<ngl_-1;j+=2)
            {
                if(i==midval && j>=midval)
                {
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j,ngl_)]=0.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j,ngl_)] =  0.25*(lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j-1,ngl_)]    +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j+1,ngl_)]  +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i-1,j,ngl_)]  +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i+1,j,ngl_)]  +
                    (h2_ * lev_Vec[x]->frc[map(i,j,ngl_)]));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=2;j<ngl_-1;j+=2)
            {
                if(i==midval && j>=midval)
                {
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j,ngl_)]=0.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j,ngl_)] = 0.25*(lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j-1,ngl_)] +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i,j+1,ngl_)]  +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i-1,j,ngl_)]  +
                    lev_Vec[x]->u_app[map(i+1,j,ngl_)]  +
                    (h2_ * lev_Vec[x]->frc[map(i,j,ngl_)]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: assign `ngl_-1` to an `int`-type local variable, and put in the condition `i<`

Comment: or typecast to int